# how to find unique value from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

below is my table called `companies`

```
company_id        Status
1001                OFF
1002                OFF
1003                OFF
1003                ON
```

I need to avoid if any `company_id` with `status 'ON'`

I need out put like below

```
company_id        Status
1001                OFF
1002                OFF
```

How i write query for this

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   company_ID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT company_ID 
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   Status = 'ON'
        )
```

or by using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT company_ID 
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   Status = 'ON'
        ) b ON a.company_ID = b.company_ID
WHERE   b.company_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbc82/1)

Comment: Correct answer but very strange way of doing this?

Comment: Check my query, isn't a simple where clause enough to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Company_Id, Status FROM Companies C 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Companies 
WHERE Company_Id = C.Company_id AND Status = 'ON')
```

Comment: @JW Don't know. This discourages us from providing solutions :(

Comment: @user2097335 That query works perfectly. Fiddle here - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b797/1

Comment: @JW its very hard to understand who downvotes. Such hopeless guys really.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT company_ID, MAX(Status) AS Status FROM companies
GROUP BY company_ID
HAVING MAX(Status) = 'OFF'
```

You can use MIN and MAX functions to sort string values. In this case MAX will return ON before OFF.